# Form 2 not showing up using system tray

Tags: c#, system-tray

I got 2 forms for a application and I am using a system tray to get it as a popup. But when I enter my username at my first form and open my second form and click at the popup icon in the bottom it doesn't work for the second form anymore.

I also have add this code at my second form.

here is the code;

```
private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FormWindowState.Minimized == this.WindowState)
    {
        notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
        notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(500);
        this.Hide();
    }
    else if (FormWindowState.Normal == this.WindowState)
    {
        notifyIcon1.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you changed from when it used to work

Comment: nothing. It just doesn't work for the second form

Comment: so your statement it "doesnt work for the second form anymore" was complete rubbish? so what exactly isnt working then, does it minimize? have you traced it to see whats going on?

Comment: I have two forms . I copied this code and put it on the first form and it works but not for the second form. The application is a login form so it has two forms and all I want is when I enter my username the first form will hide and has the minimize function which already works but when I enter my username and the second form opens and I minimize the form and click on it right in the bottom it opens the first form again.

Comment: Wow dude that explanation is super confusing

Comment: is it possible to make screen shots ?

Comment: Yeah, [edit] your question and I'll convert the links to images (you will be able to include images when you have more rep)

Comment: The code is an event for form 1 (Form1_Resize()).  To get it to work for form 2 you need to change name and to register event with a '+=' statement.  The registering is usually in the designer.cs file (text file) but can be placed in the form code in the constructor or the load method.

Comment: @jdweng do you have an example ?

Comment: here is the picture of the first from : https://gyazo.com/7037db71354b7f02349334c1844bed1b

Comment: and the second https://gyazo.com/3650f75bb0ded777e455055e40bb6c54

Comment: Using Solution Explorer open the designer file (.cs) for Form 1 and search for +=

Comment: Do i delete them ? @jdweng

Comment: Nothing need to be deleted.  The += is to register an event so the event works.  n Event doesn't work by just adding the event method.  The registering can be done in the Form properties where it is put in the designer.cs file or in you actual code.  You asked for an example so I pointed youi to the designer file.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because you have the name Form1 and Form2's resize event is not pointing to the correct function.

In design time, open the Form, press F4 to bring up the Properties window, click the Lightning Bolt icon to see the Forms events, then scroll down to Resize and choose Form2_Resize:

`private void Form2_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)`